# Why I get different result whe I output lastchar?

Tags: c++, c, linux

I have run this program, and I here below are my input and output:

```
a b     g
^Z
the counts of blanks are: 1,the counts of tabs are: 1,the counts of newlines are
: 1，the lastchar is:   10
g: 103
char type of lastchar is:

Press any key to continue
```

My question is that i think my lastchar is 'g',but why I get 10 when I output lastchar and why I get 103 when I directly output 'g'? Further more,why do I get nothing when I output lastchar by the type of char(%c)?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int blanks=0,tabs=0,newlines=0;
    int c;
    int done=0;
    int lastchar=0;


    while((c=getchar())!=EOF)
    {
        if(c==' ')
        {
            blanks++;
        }
        if(c=='\t')
        {
            tabs++;

        }
        if(c=='\n')
        {
            newlines++;
        }
        lastchar=c;


    }

    char tt='g';


    if(lastchar!='\n')
    {
        newlines++;
    }


    printf("the counts of blanks are: %d,the counts of tabs are: %d,the counts of newlines are: %d，the lastchar is: %4.0d\n",blanks,tabs,newlines,lastchar);
    printf("g: %d\n",'g');
    printf("char type of lastchar is: %c\n",lastchar); 
    return 0;




}
```

Comment: use `printf("g: %c\n",'g');` to get `g` as output `%d` will print its ascii value.

Comment: @Shwetha: `lastchar` is a variable, it doesn't "return" anything. `getchar()`, despite the name, returns `int`, and since the OP ends up storing the return value from `getchar()` in it, `int` is the appropriate type for `lastchar`. For what it's worth, `'g'` is also of type `int`, not `char`.

Comment: @Paul Griffiths: You are right. The word "return" is incorrect. I actually meant to say that using %d to print a character is not right. Somehow I conveyed it in a wrong way.

Comment: @Shwetha: Using '%d' to print a character absolutely is right, if you want to see the numeric representation of it. Obviously it isn't right if you want to see its graphical representation.

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
printf("g: %d\n",'g');
```

you're asking `printf()` to output the numeric representation (very likely ASCII) of `'g'`, which is 103.

Here:

```
printf("char type of lastchar is: %c\n",lastchar);
```

you're asking `printf()` to output `lastchar` as a character. Since the numeric value is 10, which is a linefeed, you're not seeing anything, because a linefeed is a non-printable character.

Comment: yeah,you are right,thks,and I add if(c!='\n')lastchar=c; to the code and this time I got the output of 'g' by the same input.